# microsoft/iis - A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: azure, docker, docker-for-windows, windows-container

I am trying to use containers in azure so I provisioned a "Server 2016 - with containers" VM. After doing `docker pull microsoft/iis`, I start one up like this `docker run -it microsoft/iis powershell` and execute this command:

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME
```

This is what I get:

> A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)

Using different code like `Get-NetIPAddress` or `(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'IPEnabled = True')` yields the same error. This was working without issues for quite a while.

I provisioned another container host in azure, and it gives the same error. However, if I pull down the container and run it on my Windows 10 laptop, it works. How can I fix this error?

UPDATE: If I pull down mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2016, the command completes successfully. However, somewhere in my build process, something breaks and the final container won't finish the command successfully. After that, even if I delete all the images and download the above mentioned tag fresh, it still won't complete the command without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be my use of the "graph" setting in daemon.json. I created a premium storage managed disk, and added

```
"graph":"F:\\docker"
```

to my daemon.json. After some period of time, something breaks and everything fails with the error mentioned above. Removing that line has (for the moment) caused things to work again. I wonder if it has something to do with forcing the container to pull the 3889bb8d808b layer. This layer comes with the VM on the C:\ drive but moving the data-root to F:\ causes it to be pulled again.